# Rails render: json: why does it have config->data with plain text passwords returned?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, security

[plain_text_in_json_response][1]

I just noticed this today, but why does the render JSON method add all the other information instead of just the JSON message that I ask it to return? In the config data, it includes plain text passwords...

Comment: Can you please provide some context info? Try adding the relevant code samples, for example, a controller method and a model definition along with the generated response and the expected results.

Comment: I tried to include a screenshot but it didn't work, but basically I'm looking at the response in chromes console, and I see data: config: data: (plain text password), I see my message in data: data: message: "User Updated".  The controller is basic, render json: { message: "User Updated" }, status: 200

Comment: https://pastebin.com/mVjWfCFQ